# Error in serialize the data using Marshal.load()

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing an issue when I am using the Marshal library for serealize the data. I am using "act_as_version" plugin to download the previous version files but when I serealize the data using Marshal.load() I got an error as

```
TypeError Exception: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read) format version 4.8 required; 45.45 given
```

Kindly, help to solve this issue.